# Is there an option to enter a invoice number in Twilio studio using Capture payment?

Tags: stripe-payments, twilio

I am not a programmer but I have managed to do a lot in Twilio studio. I just make a payment option on an IVR system and I want first to ask the user to enter their invoice number and that should be the description in Stripe.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a user enter a number, you can use the [*Gather Input on Call* widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/gather-input-call) to ask the user for the invoice number first.

Then in the [*Capture Payments* widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/capture-payments) you can set the Description field to the result of the *Gather* widget using [liquid templating](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide/liquid-template-language) to refer to the value of `widgets.Gather_widget_name.Digits`.